# My generate exercise button text is not showing up beofre I click the button

Tags: python, database, tkinter

The button is a tk button and it is not showing the text in the button. The button is not showing the text which make me sad and the stackoverflow is not letting me submiting this question and I am trying to write as much word as I can so I could sumbit this. Like I am adding more details

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
import os
import customtkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import io
import random


def generate_random_exercise():
global exercises_shown

# Check if all exercises have been shown
if len(exercises_shown) == len(exercises):
    exercise_label.config(text="All exercises have been shown.")
    reps_label.config(text="")
    image_label.config(image="")
    return

# Get a random exercise that hasn't been shown yet
exercise = random.choice(exercises)
while exercise in exercises_shown:
    exercise = random.choice(exercises)

exercise_name = exercise[0]
reps = exercise[1]
image_data = exercise[2]

# Display the exercise and reps
exercise_label.config(text="Exercise: " + exercise_name)
reps_label.config(text="Reps: " + str(reps))

# Load and display the image
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
image = image.resize((400, 300))  # Adjust the size as needed
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image_label.config(image=photo)
image_label.image = photo

# Add the exercise to the list of shown exercises
exercises_shown.append(exercise)

# Create a database connection
connection = sqlite3.connect("db/workout.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create the main application window
bicep = tk.Tk()
bicep.title("Bicep Exercise")
bicep.geometry("500x800")
bicep.resizable(width=False, height=False)

# Create background image
background_image = PhotoImage(file="assets/Aim high.png")
background_label = Label(bicep, image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# Get all exercises from the database
cursor.execute("SELECT exercise, reps, image FROM Biceps")
exercises = cursor.fetchall()

# Create an empty list to track the shown exercises
exercises_shown = []

# Create labels for exercise and reps
exercise_label = tk.Label(bicep, text="Exercise:", background="black", fg="white")
exercise_label.pack()

reps_label = tk.Label(bicep, text="Reps:", background="black", fg="white")
reps_label.pack()

# Create an empty label for the image
image_label = tk.Label(bicep)
image_label.pack()

# Create a button to generate random exercise
generate_button = tk.Button(bicep, text="Generate Exercise", 
command=generate_random_exercise, background="black", fg="white")
generate_button.pack()

# Close the database connection
connection.close()

bicep.mainloop()
```

The button is a tk button and it is not showing the text in the button. The button is not showing the text which make me sad and the stackoverflow is not letting me submiting this question and I am trying to write as much word as I can so I could sumbit this. Like I am adding more details

Comment: Your button has white background (although you have set it to black but it seems like it cannot be set in MacOS), and the text color is white, so you cannot see the text.  Try using another text color.

Comment: Please try to reduce the amount of code down, and also remove any use of images unless those images are critical for reproducing the problem. We don't need entire programs, we need a [mcve].

Comment: Fix the indentation.